# Set a webview view to window size

Tags: node.js, webview, electron

I am making a web browser in electron, and I have an issue where the page I open in my webview doesn't resize to the window's size and goes outside of the bounds.

Here is a picture of the issue:

[image: The issue]

If someone knows how to help me, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Do you have any styling for the webview? Like `#myWebview{ height: 100%; width: 100%; }`

Comment: The example showed in your webview is responsive?

Comment: @pushkin No, I do not have any styling.

Comment: @JonathanBrizio I do not understand your question, if you could explain it better in would be really useful.

Comment: The content that you're linking (The website) adapts to the size windows? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Comment: Have you tried to create your BrowserWindow with `useContentSize` option? See [ctor docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions)

Comment: @pergy `useContentSize` just redefines what `width` and `height` represent. It shouldn't have any effect on part of the page "leaking out" of the frame

Comment: Has my solution solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS to your window.html page:

```
/* make sure that the body fills the entire window */
body {
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    margin:0px;
}

/* make sure that the webview element fills the entire body*/
webview {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```